# WPF Listbox Show Button in ItemTemplate on MouseOver

Tags: wpf, listbox

I have a listbox containing and image and a button. By default the button is hidden. I want to make the button visible whenever I hover over an item in the listbox.
The XAML I am using is below. Thanks

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="6">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=FullPath}" Height="150" Width="150"/>
                                    <Button x:Name="sideButton" Width="20" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 55):

Ok, try this in your button declaration:

```
<Button x:Name="sideButton" Width="20">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

So I'm using a style with a trigger to look back up the visual tree until I find a `ListBoxItem`, and when its `IsMouseOver` property flips over to `True` I set the `button`'s visibility to `Visible`.

See if it's close to what you want.

Comment: In my case, I moved the style to Window.Resources and edited it like this : `x:Key="ShowHideButton" TargetType="Button"`

Each button needing this functionality just has this added:
`Style="{StaticResource ShowHideButton}`

Comment: It seems that PropertyName should be Property? +1

Answer (score 16):

This `Style` does what you need. On mouse over, the button becomes only visible when the pointer is over the `ListBoxItem`. The special trick is to bind to the `TemplatedParent` for reaching `IsMouseOver` and use `TargetName` on the `Setter` to only affect the `Button`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Margin="6">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=FullPath}"
                               Height="150"
                               Width="150" />
                        <Button x:Name="sideButton"
                                Width="20"
                                Visibility="Hidden" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility"
                                TargetName="sideButton"
                                Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: My question is: what is more efficient? To change the Button's visibility, or to create it in the MouseOver Trigger? Because I think that creating 10000 Buttons and hiding them is not that efficient that creating the concrete one in the MouseOver Trigger.

Comment: Efficient in CPU time or memory, on initialization or when mousing around? What a difference will it make in programming complexity? Try to cobble together a somewhat meaningful test case and measure it!

Answer (score 5):

@David is showing the right way, 
But I have one suggestion to your XAML architecture. If you don't have any DataBinding on the Button it is better to put that in to the ListBoxItem style than the DataTemplate as bellow.

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Margin="6">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=FullPath}"
                           Height="150"
                           Width="150" />                             
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>            
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <Button x:Name="sideButton" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Hidden" />
                        <ContentPresenter/>                            
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger  Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                            TargetName="sideButton"
                            Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>            
    </Style>
```

Comment: That looks good because it does away with the RelativeSource. I'm always reluctant to change the ControlTemplate though...

Answer (score 0):

One solution to find what item was clicked is to add the following Event setter

XAML

C#
void ListBoxItem_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _memberVar = (sender as ListBoxItem).Content;
        }

Answer (score 0):

> Just wondering, if we use the technique above, how do we determine what item the button was clicked on?

To answer Brian's question, in the button click handler you can walk up the visual tree to find the item that contains the button:

```
        DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
        while ((dep != null) && !(dep is ListBoxItem))
        {
            dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
        }

        if (dep != null)
        {
            // TODO: do stuff with the item here.
        }
```