# Silverlight ListBox OnMouseOver event

Tags: silverlight, listbox, listboxitem

I have a ListBox that is being bound to data from a WCF service.  When the user hovers over one of the ListBoxItems, I want to display related text in a separate region.  Each of the items in the data collection to which the list is being bound has a Description property.

How can I wire up to the mouseover event for a particular ListBoxItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this thread, I think you might find your answer:

[WPF Listbox Show Button in ItemTemplate on MouseOver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206495/wpf-listbox-show-button-in-itemtemplate-on-mouseover)