# Hide list item in Silverlight 4

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight application in which I display items in a list box.
I want to hide some items based on a condition, like some value of a string.

My xaml looks like this:

```
<ListBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding DashboardTypes}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDashboardCategory,Mode=TwoWay}" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyleAttribute}"
    Margin="2"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up an [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=VS.95).aspx) to describe your items and then add a binding on that for the [Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility(VS.95).aspx) property that controls when items are visible or not. I suspect that you'll need a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=VS.95).aspx) to actually implement the rule for when an item should be visible.

There is a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206495/wpf-listbox-show-button-in-itemtemplate-on-mouseover) that covers [something similar but in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206495/wpf-listbox-show-button-in-itemtemplate-on-mouseover). It should give you some pointers that will help you in implementing this.