# WPF ListBoxItem detect IsMouseOver inside a custom item

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem, ismouseover

i have a ListBox which I fill with custom items. I want to detect a MouseOver event from a ListBoxItem inside the item in order to change visibility of a button. I have checked most of the answers on StackOverflow, the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206495/wpf-listbox-show-button-in-itemtemplate-on-mouseover) solution was what I was looking for, but it doesn't work.

This is a code snippet from my ContactsView:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="ListBox_OnScrollChanged"  BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PrimaryColor}" Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxItemsSource}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <events:RoutedEventTrigger RoutedEvent="ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=ListBoxScrollChangedCommand}" />
            </events:RoutedEventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=ListBoxLoadedCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>

                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ListBoxItem.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ListBoxItem.IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <!-- Custom item -->
                    <items:ItemCorporateContact Value="{Binding Path=., Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    <Separator Height="1" Margin="0" Background="#ececec" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

And I have been trying to detect the event this way (code from a custom item that I add to a ListBox):

```
<Button Name="StartCallButton" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Red" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource PhoneIconBitmap}"></Image>
                    </Button.Content>
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had been searching for the same thing. Although the answer is provided in the question, but to specify the answer more clearly, following is the code that works for me.

```
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="ViewTypeStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Border BorderThickness="2,0,0,0" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverterInstance}}" BorderBrush="Blue"/>
                            <Image Height="32" Width="32">
                                <Image.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="Image">
                                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path=ImagePath}"/>
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path=ImagePathHover}"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </Image.Style>
                            </Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```